# Access to PyPi via Http (not https)

Tags: python, ssl, artifactory, pypi

I work in a secure environment where the company proxy does a man-in-the-middle attack on all inbound traffic. That means any HTTPS comes to me with a broken certificate.

It's unlikely that I'm going to be able to convince our network security people to stop doing this on my account. I'm not even going to try to fix that problem.

Unfortunately this affects my use of PyPI: I want to set up an Artifactory repository to mirror PyPI internally, but since the certificates are messed up Artifactory rejects any content.

It used to be possible to access PyPI's repository via HTTP, but this feature seems to have been recently disabled. I was wondering if there's an alternative way to access PyPI that doesn't use HTTPS - perhaps some barely documented back door?

The only alternative I can think of is to spin up a reverse proxy on AWS/Azure and use that to permit insecure access. Any suggestions?

Comment: it's only broken if you don't recognize the authority that issues the certificate. You can install it on the machine that needs to access https content.

Comment: I have no idea what artifactory is, but how do you want to access PyPI? Through pip, or via code? Would be nice if you could add this detail :)